# while TRUE + break in a sub-environment

Tags: r, while-loop, break

I'm having trouble getting a `while(TRUE)` loop to work. This example I think gets at the crux of the problem:

```
l <- list(x = 5)

while (TRUE){
  with(l, if (x > 100) break else l$x <<- x + 5)
}
```

Which runs with error:

> Error in `eval(expr, envir, enclos)` :
>
> no loop for break/next, jumping to top level

Strangely, the `while` loop appears to have executed successfully:

```
l
# $x
# [1] 105
```

It appears the problem is I'm sending the `break` statement in a sub-environment, since the following works as expected without error:

```
x = 5

while(TRUE){
  if (x > 100) break else x <<- x+5
}
```

Thinking it's just an environments issue, I also tried replacing `break` with `eval(break, parent.env())` and `eval(break, parent.frame())`, to no avail.

How can I stop this error?

---

I suppose `sessionInfo()` may be relevant:

```
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readxl_0.1.0.9000 data.table_1.9.6  haven_0.2.0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rsconnect_0.4.1.11 tools_3.2.4        Rcpp_0.12.1        chron_2.3-47
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `with`? Why not just `if (l$x>100) break else l$x<-l$x+100`?

Comment: @nicola the context of the problem is slightly different; I chose this to replicate what I believe to be the essentials. That said, in my actual usage, `break` is sent within a call to `[.data.table`

Comment: Maybe better explaining the context would be helpful, since here it is cleary an environment issue: `while(TRUE) with(l,break)` produces the same error. Apparently `with` produces an environment from which R doesn't expect to `break`.

Comment: R's `with` is just a function. So you are essentially doing this: `while(TRUE) {(function() break)()}`. The `break` is in the scope of the inner function, while the `while` is in the outer.

Comment: @AWebb thanks, I'm aware of the `with`-equals-function bit, the trouble was in figuring out where exactly to evaluate the `break` since `while` is working in its own environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variant of @Vongo's suggestion is to capture the environment in which the evaluation is supposed to occur with `environment()`, and then use `evalq()` to have the `break` evaluated in the right place.

```
l <- list(x = 5)
while (TRUE){
    env <- environment()
    with(l, if (x > 100) evalq(break, env) else l$x <<- x + 5)
}
```

This avoids parsing a text string and seems for that reason less hacky. Evaluating in the the captured environment `env` allows the loop to be at any level in R code, not just in .GlobalEnv. This is like a non-local jump (aka GOTO) which makes it more difficult to reason about the code.

Comment: also `evalq(break, parent.env(environment()))`. I'm still not sure why the original code was not an infinite loop if `break` was sent to the wrong environment. Any reason?

Comment: @MichaelChirico better to be explicit about env= rather than relying on the order of the call stack for discovery, since the programmer may inadvertently change the call stack. The original code generated an error, and as a consequence of the error the loop ended.

Comment: Ohh that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand all the stakes of the problem, but you could try :

```
l <- list(x = 5)
while (TRUE){
  with(l, if (x > 100) eval(parse(text="break"), envir=.GlobalEnv) else l$x <<- x + 5)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just coming back. I think that @Martin Morgan explained this approach and even improved it. Kudos !